# HTML design alignment

Tags: html, css

I used fireworks with netbeans to make php website. First i sliced my design with fireworks and exported into netbeans. Now on netbeans it created css and html files.

The problem is, my design is 960px wide and it should come center of the webbrowser and there should be background on both sides. But now it is showing on left aligned.

Obviosly there is something in css that makes it left aligned . So question is how can i make it centered ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect us to tell what the problem is without seeing the code?

Comment: how can i put my whole code here on public plateform.

Comment: I would recommend against doing such things. Make a mockup in photoshop or illustrator or paint or whatever, then write it from scratch. It creates much more powerful and semantically correct designs.

Comment: There is no way we can really tell what you mean without some code, but in general centering your wrapper should be possible with `margin:0 auto;` if you have no other errors in your code...

Comment: Just put the problematic code, the CSS and HTML.

Comment: @mann prepend it with 4 spaces. `    code`, if you have multiple lines, paste it, highlight it, and press CTRL+K. see the [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use strict doctype, you may apply the following margin on the container:

```css
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: yes tried this does not effect anything